# Oracle Invalid Number

Tags: oracle, datetime, model-view-controller

I am trying to search between to dates and do the paging. But i take error 'ORA-01722: invalid number'
how can i solve this thanks.

```
 public IEnumerable<LaboratuvarTest> ListePagingTariheGore(int SAYFA, DateTime tarihbaslangic, DateTime tarihbitis)
    {
        string tarihbas = tarihbaslangic.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        string tarihbit = tarihbitis.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateTime b = tarihbaslangic.ToLocalTime();
        DateTime d = tarihbitis.Date;
        if (!connection.Baglan()) return null;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT a.*, rownum r__ FROM(SELECT ID,BARKOD,RUTUBET,COPSAP,OKSIDEEDILMEMISPARCA,VOLUM,DUYUSALANALIZ,DUSUNCELER,TADIM,AMBALAJKONTROL,KASAYADOKULENCAY,SELULOZ,EKSTRAT,DURUM FROM HAR_TBLLABORATUVARTEST WHERE DURUM = 1 AND TESTTARIHI BETWEEN TO_CHAR(:p2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_CHAR(:p3, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ORDER BY TESTTARIHI DESC )a WHERE rownum < ((:p1 * 5) + 1) ) WHERE r__ >= (((:p1 - 1) * 5) + 1)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", SAYFA);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", tarihbas);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", tarihbit);
        cmd.Connection = connection.con;

        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<LaboratuvarTest> list = new List<LaboratuvarTest>().FromDataReader(reader).ToList();
        connection.BaglantiKapat();
        return list; ;
    }
```

'ORA-01722: invalid number'

```
ID  NUMBER(5,0)
BARKOD  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
RUTUBET NUMBER(8,0)
COPSAP  NUMBER(8,0)
OKSIDEEDILMEMISPARCA    NUMBER(8,0)
VOLUM   NUMBER(8,0)
DUYUSALANALIZ   NUMBER(8,0)
DUSUNCELER  VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
TADIM   VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
AMBALAJKONTROL  VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
KASAYADOKULENCAY    NUMBER(3,0)
SELULOZ VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
EKSTRAT VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
TESTTARIHI  DATE
KULLANICIREF    NUMBER(5,0)
DURUM   NUMBER(1,0)
```

this the table

{01.08.2018 00:00:00} 
{14.08.2018 00:00:00} these are dates which are coming to func.

I can select when i run the first select query inside but these 3 can't run together idk why

Comment: you will need to give the column types for all the fields used in your query. `Invalid number` error message can popup for a few different reasons.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table's definition

Answer (score 1):

The `tarihbas` and `tarihbit` paramenters you bind to the query are already strings, you shouldn't call `to_char` on them. In fact, you shouldn't use strings there at all - you should use the dates directly:

```
TESTTARIHI BETWEEN :p2 AND p3
```

And bind `tarihbaslangic` and `tarihbitis` as `p2` and `p3`, respectively.

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER'
 this error coming right now

Answer (score 0):

The oracle query you are using needs correction.
Make sure that :p2 and :p2 bind variable are String in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy';

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT a.*, rownum r__ FROM(SELECT ID,BARKOD,RUTUBET,COPSAP,OKSIDEEDILMEMISPARCA,VOLUM,DUYUSALANALIZ,DUSUNCELER,TADIM,AMBALAJKONTROL,KASAYADOKULENCAY,SELULOZ,EKSTRAT,DURUM FROM HAR_TBLLABORATUVARTEST WHERE DURUM = 1 AND TESTTARIHI BETWEEN TO_DATE(:p2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(:p3, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ORDER BY TESTTARIHI DESC )a WHERE rownum < ((:p1 * 5) + 1) ) WHERE r__ >= (((:p1 - 1) * 5) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your parameters as strings, and populate them like this:

```
tarihbas = tarihbaslangic.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

However, when you use those in the query you try to cast them as strings again:

```
TESTTARIHI BETWEEN TO_CHAR(:p2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_CHAR(:p3, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

As they are already strings and as TESTTARIHI is date it would make more sense to cast them to dates:

```
TESTTARIHI BETWEEN TO_date(:p2, 'dd-mm/yyyy') and TO_date(:p3, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Even better would be to pass the parameters as DATEs and avoid the need for datatype conversion altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can change data parse like that

DateTime.Parse(dr["TARIH"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yy");

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. It's because order from parameters. 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", tarihbas);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", tarihbit);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", SAYFA);` in this style it will work. So annoying error.